# Importing through folders

Tags: python

I just want to make it clear that I'm not nooby at Python, and I am fully aware on how to import files, and use 'from' to import through folders.

However I want to import through two folders, if that makes sense. Say I have a folder called 'First Folder', and inside that folder I have another called 'Second Folder', I want to import a file called 'Goal.py' which resides inside the Second Folder.

I have done a little research but could not find anything that actually answered my question.

Is it super simple, like:

```
 from SecondFolder from FirstFolder import Goal
```

or is it something else? Thanks in advance

Comment: The way you write your question seems to imply that you didn't test it yet. What have you tried so far to make it work?

Comment: on a side note, please read about python modules (this is regarding `__init__.py` from the answer), then read about pep-8 (syntax, case and how to format code) - module names should be lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
from first.second import abc
```

But file hierarchy should be like this.

```
.
|-- first
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- second
        |-- abc.py
        |-- __init__.py
```